# Why file is not uploading properly using my flutter code but gets uploaded in postman?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I use the function given below to upload file in AWS s3 bucket I get path like something this **https://rightcaimcustomerdocuments.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/1688348195538gio** look it when I upload same file using same API I get string something like this "path": **"https://rightcaimcustomerdocuments.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/1688899728040gio.png"** Now I can use this link to access that file but is this happening.
I am using multiparts for uploading the file.
I am not sure but it looks like there is some problem with the **selectFile** function

```
static Column uploadFileDialog(
      BuildContext parentContext, String userIdString) {
    TextEditingController docNameController = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController expiryDateController = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController reminderController = TextEditingController();

    File? selectedFile;
    String? filePath;
    Future<void> selectFile(BuildContext context) async {
      FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();

      if (result != null && result.files.isNotEmpty) {
        selectedFile = File(result.files.single.path!);
      }
    }

    DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();
    print(selectedDate.month);
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text(
          "Upload Documents",
          style: CommonTextStyles.text18_700(),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 15,
        ),
        TextField(
          controller: docNameController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
            prefixIconColor: ColorConstants.textFormIconColor,
            suffixIconColor: ColorConstants.textFormIconColor,
            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16, color: ColorConstants.textFormIconColor),
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.folder_outlined, size: 24),
            hintText: "Document Name",
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        TextField(
          readOnly: true,
          controller: expiryDateController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
            prefixIconColor: ColorConstants.textFormIconColor,
            suffixIconColor: ColorConstants.textFormIconColor,
            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16, color: ColorConstants.textFormIconColor),
            prefixIcon: Icon(
              Icons.hourglass_top,
              size: 24,
            ),
            hintText: "Expiry Date",
            suffixIcon: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.calendar_today,
                size: 20,
              ),
              onPressed: () async {
                final DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
                  context: parentContext,
                  initialDate: selectedDate,
                  firstDate: DateTime(2000),
                  lastDate: DateTime(2100),
                );

                if (pickedDate != null) {
                  selectedDate = pickedDate;
                  String day = pickedDate.day.toString(),
                      month = pickedDate.month.toString(),
                      year = pickedDate.year.toString();
                  if (pickedDate.day < 10) {
                    day = "0" + day;
                  }
                  if (pickedDate.month < 10) {
                    month = "0" + month;
                    print(month);
                  }

                  expiryDateController.text = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
                  print(reminderController.text);
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        TextField(
          readOnly: true,
          controller: reminderController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
            prefixIconColor: ColorConstants.textFormIconColor,
            suffixIconColor: ColorConstants.textFormIconColor,
            prefixIcon: Icon(
              Icons.alarm,
              size: 24,
            ),
            hintText: "Reminder",
            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16, color: ColorConstants.textFormIconColor),
            suffixIcon: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.calendar_today,
                size: 20,
              ),
              onPressed: () async {
                final DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
                  context: parentContext,
                  initialDate: selectedDate,
                  firstDate: DateTime(2000),
                  lastDate: DateTime(2100),
                );
                if (pickedDate != null) {
                  selectedDate = pickedDate;
                  String day = pickedDate.day.toString(),
                      month = pickedDate.month.toString(),
                      year = pickedDate.year.toString();
                  if (pickedDate.day < 10) {
                    day = "0" + day;
                  }
                  if (pickedDate.month < 10) {
                    month = "0" + month;
                    print(month);
                  }

                  reminderController.text = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
                  print(reminderController.text);
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        Consumer<FileSelectionProvider>(
          builder: (context, value, child) {
            return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () async {
                  await selectFile(context);
                  if (selectedFile != null) {
                    filePath = selectedFile!.path;
                    print("The file path is this");

                    Provider.of<FileSelectionProvider>(context, listen: false)
                        .switchFileSelection();
                    print("file was selected again");
                  } else {
                    print("File not selected properly");
                  }
                },
                child: (value.intitialFileSelectionState.fileSelected == false)
                    ? DottedBorder(
                        color: ColorConstants.tertiaryColor,
                        borderType: BorderType.RRect,
                        radius: Radius.circular(12),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                          child: Container(
                            height: 35,
                            width: 180,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                            ),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.ios_share,
                                  color: ColorConstants.tertiaryColor,
                                  size: 20,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width: 10),
                                Text(
                                  "Upload Documents",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: ColorConstants.tertiaryColor,
                                      fontSize: 15),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    : Container(
                        height: 40,
                        width: 150,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: ColorConstants.tertiaryColor,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                        child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Spacer(),
                              Text(
                                "File Name",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              Spacer(),
                              IconButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  selectedFile = null;
                                  Provider.of<FileSelectionProvider>(context,
                                          listen: false)
                                      .switchFileSelection();
                                },
                                icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )
                            ]),
                      ));
          },
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        Text("File size limit: 100MB  Allowed file type: Word, Excel, PPT, PDF",
            style: CommonTextStyles.text16_400()!
                .copyWith(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.black)),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                Navigator.of(parentContext).pop();
                FocusScope.of(parentContext).unfocus();
              },
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                elevation: 0,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                  side: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.black),
                ),
                minimumSize: Size(83, 40),
              ),
              child: Text(
                "Cancel",
                style: CommonTextStyles.text16_500()?.copyWith(
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            CommonElevatedButton.smallButtons(
              text: "Upload",
              onPressed: () async {
                String userId = userIdString;
                String uploadAt = reminderController.text;
                String expiredAt = expiryDateController.text;
                String filename = docNameController.text;
                await uploadFileToApi( selectedFile, userId,
                    uploadAt, expiredAt, filename);
                final reloadedData = await getUserDetails(userId.toString());
                print("This is after delete");
                print(reloadedData);
                final folderProvider =
                    Provider.of<FolderProvider>(parentContext, listen: false);
                folderProvider.updateGridData(reloadedData);
                foldersList = folderProvider.gridData.folderList;
                Provider.of<EmptyFilesProvider>(parentContext, listen: false)
                    .switchFileState();

                Navigator.of(parentContext).pop();
                FocusScope.of(parentContext).unfocus();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: remove unnecessary code above, and add the code reasonable for  select & upload the file

Answer (score 0):

try this code snippet

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:aws_s3/aws_s3.dart';

void main() async {
  // Create a new S3 client.
  final s3Client = S3Client();

  // Get the file path from the `FileSelectionProvider` class.
  final filePath = Provider.of<FileSelectionProvider>(context, listen: false).filePath;

  // Upload the file to S3.
  await s3Client.putObject(
    bucket: 'my-bucket',
    key: 'my_file.pdf',
    file: File(filePath),
  );
}
```